# Keep object size constant when rotating 3-D Matlab plot

Tags: matlab, 3d, plot, matlab-figure

I am trying to generate a set of views of a 3-D object in Matlab such that the angle changes but the object size stays constant. Because Matlab tries to fit the entire axis into view, an object will shrink or grow depending on whether the plot is viewed head-on or at an angle. As an example:

```
[x,y,z] = sphere(50); % coordinates of a sphere
surf(x,y,z);          % plot the sphere
axis image off
view(0,0)             % at this angle the sphere fills the axes
view(-37.5,30)        % at this angle the sphere is much smaller
```

How can I make it so that the sphere appears the same size no matter what angle it's viewed at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`axis`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) function is your friend here. Try adding

```
axis vis3d
```

From the help, "axis VIS3D  freezes aspect ratio properties to enable rotation of 3-D objects and overrides stretch-to-fill." If you're interested The same this can be accomplished via

```
ax = gca;
props = {'CameraViewAngle','DataAspectRatio','PlotBoxAspectRatio'};
set(ax,props,get(ax,props));
```

Comment: axis vis3d makes the title be cropped

Comment: axis vis3d also makes the plot very small in the figure. Even if I maximize the figure the plot shows with lots of spacer around it. Is there a way to fit to the window?